# Label tap event delay

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

There is some difference in perfomance between using tap event on label and on button component. 
Lets take for example this nativescript hello world app

https://github.com/NativeScript/template-hello-world

And especially this code

```html
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo">
  <StackLayout>
    <Label text="Tap the button" class="title"/>
    <Button text="TAP" tap="{{ onTap }}" />
    <Label text="{{ message }}" class="message" textWrap="true"/>
  </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

When i am tapping fast on the button the UI is updated smoothly, but when i change the Button component with Label and try to tap fast there is some delay with updating the UI or some of the taps are not handled and the message property is not updated correctly.

I am using android (5.0) genymotion and real device (Android 6)

Nativescript: 2.2

The "problem" occurs in nativescript angular2 too.

Comment: This could be caused be differences in the  implementation of tap event for the Label and the Button. For the Button for android has been used android `OnTouchListener` and for the other views which extends base view has been used gestures.

Comment: With the nativescript touch gesture everything is ok. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can give the tap event to the layout containers containing labels to increase the maximum touchable area.

```
<StackLayout (tap)="yourFunction()">
<Label text = "click event"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```